# Hide WooCommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a site and using WooCommerce. My purchased theme is supporting WooCommerce.

by Default WooCommerce make a shop page where it shows the archives of products and other page that i have made is Packages where all the packages are showing with categories.

Now i want to completely hide this page and block it in SEO

```
www.abc.com/shop/
```

I just want to show this page

```
www.abc.com/packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i figured it out.

Basically there are 2 pages

1) shop - which is working as an archive page to list down products.

2) Packages - which is custom designed and showing products in different category

Now I don't want users to view (shop) page so I installed a plugin which redirects the user to second page (packages)

Answer (score 1):

In your dashboard go

- WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products
- Change the Product Archive / Shop Page from `Shop` to `packages` and save the changes

Next

- Go to the Settings tab on your dashboard -> Permalinks
- Scroll to the bottom of the page
- Change `Product permalink base` to `Shop base`
- Save those changes and going to `www.abc.com/packages` should show the products

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question. I want to hide shop (archive page) which is default taken by WooCommerce to display products

Comment: I am sorry, i don't understand. You don't want any products listed in the `shop` page?